# How to use ROS on Windows 10

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, windows, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am new in ROS.
I need to use ROS on Windows 10. I have installed ROS and I can run "rosrun".
I had followed this instruction http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows . It works.

But I dont understand how to use packages which I need. For example, I need "libuvc_camera" or "usb_cam", "stereo_image_proc" and "rtab_map".
But I don't find any information about how to launch them using ROS on Windows.
Shall I compile them by myself?

Please, explain me what I need to do for make it works. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348362/how-to-use-ros-on-windows-10/) by [Quetalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/53202/quetalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for the delay in responding.

We have quite a bit of documentation on http://aka.ms/ros/docs which walk though the process of consuming ROS nodes.

There is a [Windows specific Camera](https://github.com/ms-iot/ros_win_camera) node, which is custom tailored for performance on Windows.

For ROS nodes without binary packages, you'll want to clone them into your workspace, and may have to do tweaks to build them. Here's a link to the [docs consuming a package](https://ms-iot.github.io/ROSOnWindows/GettingStarted/UsingROSonWindows.html)

If you have any problems, feel free to create an issue on https://github.com/ms-iot/rosonwindows.

Lou

---

Originally posted by [OoeyGUI](https://answers.ros.org/users/37999/ooeygui/) with karma: 186 on 2020-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1